# ASP.NET Login web controller Textbox

Tags: asp.net, authentication, input, textbox, placeholder

I just wonder if it is possible to have placeholder for text boxes of a log in?
I am using `<asp:Login runat="server"> </asp:Login>` and i want to access over textboxes.

I have login page which i made using `<asp:Login runat="server"> </asp:Login>`, as you know the login form has 2 fields one username and one password, i don't want to use any label for them, however i have to show what is the field, by something. i thought using a placeholder which will disappear as soon as someone types in something. in normal form i can use `<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" /`> but in this case i can not access the field.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you expand on what you mean please?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sure!
I have login page which i made using <asp:Login runat="server"> </asp:Login>, as you know the login form has 2 fields one username and one password, i don't want to use any label for them, however i have to show what is the field, by something. i thought using a placeholder which will disappear as soon as someone types in something. in normal form i can use    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" />   but in this case i can not access the field.

Comment: I think it would help to post your extra details in the question itself. That will make it easier for people to read. You can do this by clicking on edit underneath the question.